# Data driven Testing using Postman

Tags: get, postman

I am using POSTMAN Client and trying to read data from csv file. As a PoC, I have used below end point url

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Light In August

Below is my code

```html
tests["Status code is 200"] = responseCode.code === 200;

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("requestBook", data.requestBook);

var response = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["Validate the title is correctly populated"] = /{{title}}/.test(response.items[0].volumeInfo.title);
tests["Validate the author is correctly populated"] = /{{authors}}/.test(response.items[0].volumeInfo.authors);
tests["Validate the publisher is correctly populated"] = /{{publisher}}/.test(response.items[0].volumeInfo.publisher);
tests["Validate the published date is correctly populated"] = /{{publishedDate}}/.test(response.items[0].volumeInfo.publishedDate);
tests["Validate the page count is correctly populated"] = /{{pageCount}}/.test(response.items[0].volumeInfo.pageCount);
tests["Validate the category is correctly populated"] = /{{categories}}/.test(response.items[0].volumeInfo.categories);
tests["Validate the amount is correctly populated"] = /{{amount}}/.test(response.items[0].saleInfo.listPrice.amount);
tests["Validate the currency code is correctly populated"] = /{{currencyCode}}/.test(response.items[0].saleInfo.listPrice.currencyCode);
```

It is failing. When i check my csv file, its all looks fine

Note: When I click the preview all my data shows with double quoted

Comment: I have found the solution hence its resolved. The new code is tests["Validate the title is correctly populated"] = response.items[0].volumeInfo.title === data.title;

Comment: Write this comment as an answer instead and accept it. It will earn you a small bit of reputation and make it easier for other developers as well to see the answer.

Comment: I tried but unable to find button says "Answer"

Comment: There's a big text field at the bottom of this page that has the heading "Your Answer". And below that there's a button called "Post Your Answer."
Or maybe I didn't understand you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution hence its resolved. The new code is tests["Validate the title is correctly populated"] = response.items[0].volumeInfo.title === data.title;